# Why is this Javascript code executed twice?

Tags: javascript

When a link is clicked on my site the Javascript code below is executed, if the condition is true it will display an alert dialog. When the user selects the OK button in the alert dialog the block of code is executed again.

So the alert closes, the code below is executed for a second time and the alert dialog is displayed again. When the used selects the OK button on the alert dialog the second time the alert dialog is closed for good.

How can I prevent the code below being executed twice?

```
$("#my-button").click(function() {
    var login = someVar;
    if(!someVar || someVar == ''){
        $('.close-reveal-modal').click(); 
        alert(myMessage);
    }
});
```

Comment: please post the html or try to reproduce it on jsfiddle

Comment: Does #my-button also have a class of .close-reveal-modal, by any chance?

Comment: @evilbhonda - wouldn't that send it into an infinite loop of alerts?

Comment: @RobH maybe, I'd need to check.  But from the limited code that's provided, that's the part that jumped out at me

Comment: Can you be adding the same code (click handler) twice?

Comment: @user86834 what is the meaning of this line here , `$('.close-reveal-modal').click();' are you trying to register it without any callback function or trying to trigger  `click()` event.

Comment: No, I moved onto something else, back on it now though.

Comment: @user86834, can you answer some of the questions in the comments so we can help more?

Comment: You were right Sergio, the click handler was being added twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are adding the click handler twice, maybe that is what is causing that behavior.

In that case remove one of them.

Answer (score 1):

From the very limited information that's provided, this is all that I can think of as going wrong:

```
$('.close-reveal-modal').click();
```

This piece of code should have some kind of function which is executed to display a similar Alert Box.

A complete code would be more useful for a complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

Might not have anything to do with that code at all. Check to make sure that your javascript file isn't being called twice in the same app.

Answer (score 0):

From what we have here, I'm guessing that your `.close-reveal-modal` element is in `#my-button` (or is the same html node).

When you trigger the click on it (by `$('.close-reveal-modal').click();`), it also trigger the click on its parent node, so on `#my-button` too.

I can be wrong, we need the HTML part (a fiddle would be great) to validate my theory.